# Facebook integration using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, html, cordova

I'm using Phonegap 2.3 and Android for developing my app. I'm trying to integrate Facebook login in my app. I had used the plugin available in GitHub. I had integrated the plugin successfully, but when trying to login using facebook login i'm getting error as

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

Please suggest some ideas for fixing the bug.

Comment: Which [facebook login][1] integrated into the application: for [web][2] or for [native android][3]?


  [1]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
  [2]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/
  [3]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-android

Comment: [This][1] has the same issue listed. If it helps !


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184632/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration

Comment: I had tried the suggestions given in forum,but still my problem persist. I had added the configuration required in the facebook app page & in the application too, but problem still exist