# How can I add localhost:3000 to Facebook App for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I am working on a Rails 4 app. On my laptop, development is done at `localhost:3000`. The actual domain of the site is `roomidex.com`.

How can I set up a Facebook app so it works on production and development?

Here is the current configuration:

```
App Domains: roomidex.com

Website With Facebook Login: 
Site URL: http://www.roomidex.com
```

When I try to do a Facebook login on localhost:3000, I get this not surprising error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

On the Facebook App page, click "edit App" then click "Advanced" in the left-hand navigation. Then for "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" add `http://localhost:3000`... or whatever you want the accepted redirect to be.

Comment: Facebook recently changed their UI so this answer doesn't seem valid anymore.  Do you know what to do for the new UI?

Comment: Worked for me: create new app -> go to Advanced and paste http://localhost:3000 under "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"

Comment: FYI - just wanted to add that Facebook has Test App support now, so you  can have one production app, create a test app from that, and individually manage OAuth redirect URIs (don't forget to use the test app credentials, of course). This gives you better control and does not open localhost to your production App

Comment: New layout location to get here is under the Settings (left nav) then Advanced (top, middle of page)

Comment: For me it was under the "Facebook Login" in the left-hand menu, under the "Products" heading.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a test app that's connected to your main app.  On the Dashboard or Settings page for your main app. scroll down and you'll see "Test Apps" in the menu that runs down the left side of the page.  The test app will inherit settings from the main app, but it will permanently be in development mode, and it will have its own ID.

More info on test apps here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

The protocol for setting up an app to work on localhost has changed.  After you get your test app set up, this explains the steps for setting it up to work on localhost:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24253054/2803458

Answer (score 4):

Your error is saying

> localhost URL is not allowed in the application

I know, FB does not give a s**t about explaining, what do to in those moments, however, as far as I am concerned, I have found workaround.

Basically, you need to "whitelist" locahost url in your app

**Here is what you are going to do**

1. Go to the app edit/summary page
2. In the fourth field ***App Domains***, you should already have `roomidex.com`, so add another address `localhost`
3. The urls mentioned above are only valid, if each one of them is put into tabs, where you set, how you `app integrates with Facebook` (website with facebook login, App on facebook, Mobile web, …)
4. I do this: I put my working URL, in your case **roomidex.com** into `Website with facebook login`, and my test, **localhost** URL, either into `App on facebook` or `Page tab`

Answer (score 1):

June 2015

Go to My Apps > Settings > Basic

### App Domains

- localhost

### Site Web

- URL : http://localhost:8888/
- Mobile URL : http://localhost:8888/

It didn't work with port 80 or without any port unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `localhost` to the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` in the test app **did not** work for me but adding `127.0.0.1` did.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook now requires "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" to be https.

To use https locally (localhost:3000), I used [ngrok][1] which allows you to use https by providing a tunnel.  To do this:

1. I went to their website and downloaded their program
2. I extracted the file for the program
3. In my console, I went into the directory where ngrok was extracted to and entered 'grok http 3000' on my Windows machine, others may use './grok http 3000'
4. After entering that, ngrok provided a https address which I put into the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field in Facebook
5. Then I started my server and was able to access it using that https address instead of localhost:3000

Answer (score -1):

Just create two applications.

One for testing and one for release. You cannot supply the app with separate URL configurations.

Comment: Isn't that a lot of extra work? Is there a good reason FB does not allow you to add localhost in the same app?

Comment: Facebook allows "Test Apps." First create a production/release app, and then create a child of that app for testing and other purposes. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

Answer (score -4):

Just edit your hosts file with your domain that pointing to localhost and it should work fine.