# Testing Facebook app from Localhost

Tags: facebook, authomatic

I can't test my facebook app from my local computer. I have tried:

- Website url: http://localhost:8000
- Domain: localhost
- Call back URl: http://localhost/login

I am using the authomatic python library. The result object from result = authomatic.login(DjangoAdapter(request, html_response), 'fb') returns nothing. I don't think the issue is to do with authomatic as it works on the production site.

I've also tried the different combinations in the related question [Facebook App: localhost no longer works as app domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295872/facebook-app-localhost-no-longer-works-as-app-domain)

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: This question is unclear. What are the errors?

Comment: Sorry - I've added more details