# "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains" error on Facebook login. Localhost

Tags: javascript, facebook, localhost

[I followed the instructions in the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295872/facebook-app-localhost-no-longer-works-as-app-domain) and set localhost as my app domain and http://localhost:3000/ as my site URL & oauth redirect URL. I have also enabled Facebook login down in products.

What am I messing up?

Comment: Double-check that you used the correct app id.

Comment: @CBroe Yup, I used the right one >_<

Answer (score 0):

write on domain http://localhost/project_name

or if you use port then type

http://localhost:port/project_name