# Facebook OAuth “The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain” with localhost:3000

Tags: ruby, omniauth

Trying to create a basic login authentication system via OmniAuth-Facebook and Ruby that uses `http ://localhost:3000/`. Already implemented this `(http:// localhost:3000/` into Site URL and Valid OAuth redirect URIs on FacebookDev.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?  Hard to help without seeing at least error message and perhaps some code.

Comment: "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings." - This is the error

Answer (score 1):

It might not like localhost.  Can you try to use something like `http://myapp.dev`  and forward that domain in your `etc/hosts` file?  Assuming your on *nix system add a line:

```
127.0.0.1   myapp.dev
```

then in the fb app settings use:

```
http://myapp.dev
```

But the app name should match your facebook app name.

Also have a look here:  [Facebook App: localhost no longer works as app domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295872/facebook-app-localhost-no-longer-works-as-app-domain/38173031#38173031)

Answer (score 0):

To solve ensure that Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs is set to No.

This is found in the Facebook Login section of the developer page.