# How to test Facebook login locally

Tags: php, localhost, facebook-login

I need to test facebook login function in localhost. I have created virtual host

> local.sitename.com

. Also edited the host file

> 127.0.0.1 local.sitename.com

I already have an app. So I edited the app site url to:

> http://local.sitename.com/

Also added sitedomains.

But below error comes

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184632/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration)

Comment: Thanks. I have done everything correct but the url. I haven't given the virtualhost url correct. Solved